# standard sequential algorithm with polylog runtime?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

At the Wikipedia article on [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), only a PRAM example is given for polylogarithmic time.

Let $T(n)$ denote the largest number of steps used by a machine to reach a final state on any input with size $n$ bits.

> Is there a program for a standard sequential model of computation (e.g. a Turing machine or a sequential random-access machine), solving some natural problem, so that $T(n) \in \Theta((\log n)^k)$ for some fixed $k>1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where each operation is $ O\left(\log^kn\right)$ amortized/expected; I don't know if necessarily $\Theta\left(\log^kn\right)$:

- Dynamic graph connectivity algorithms

  - [***Poly-Logarithmic Deterministic Fully-Dynamic Algorithms
    for Connectivity, Minimum Spanning Tree, 2-Edge,
    and Biconnectivity***](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.89.919) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.919&rep=rep1&type=pdf))
  - [***Dynamic graph connectivity in polylogarithmic worst case time***](http://knowledgecenter.siam.org/0236-000016/0236-000016/1) ([PDF](http://knowledgecenter.siam.org/0236-000016/0236-000016/~~PdfSource/0), [slides](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~val/Publications/SODA13slides.pdf))
  - [***Fully Dynamic 2-Edge Connectivity Algorithm in
    Polylogarithmic Time per Operation***](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.8906) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.37.8906&rep=rep1&type=pdf))
  - [Lists of connectivity problems](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/scribe/L20.pdf)
- [***Maintaining Dynamic Sequences under Equality Tests
  in Polylogarithmic Time***](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.94.3489) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.94.3489&rep=rep1&type=pdf))
- Distances and point-sets:

  - [***Maintaining the miminal distance of a point set in polylogarithmic time***](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/research.html) ([PDF](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/closestpairpolylog.pdf), $O\left(\log^2n\right)$, Smid)
  - [***New techniques for some dynamic closest-point and farthest-point problems***](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320176.320185) ($O\left(\log^D n\right)$ Supowit)
  - [***New Techniques For Exact And Approximate Dynamic Closest-Point Problems***](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.1464) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.1464&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Kapoor, Smid, $O\left(\log^D n \log \log n\right)$, though cites others with just $O(polylog)$)
  - [***TOPP 63: Dynamic Planar Nearest Neighbors***](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P63.html), lists 3 papers with data structures that have operations that run in $O\left(log^k n\right)$ time
  - [Point location algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location),
  - Monotone subdivisions, without fractional cascading, query-time is $O\left(\log^2 n\right)$
  - Best known algorithms for point-location in higher-dimensions ($\gt 2$) have a trade-off; $O\left(\log n\right)$ query-time has large memory requirements that make them unscaleable. Reducing the memory requirements (for example to $O\left(n\log n\right)$ results in query-times of $O\left(\log^k n\right)$
- [***Efficient Partition Trees***](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.94.2130) ([PDF](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~sgovinda/Course/papers/M92.pdf), Matousek, $O\left(\log^2 n\right)$ insertion time)
- [***An Implicit Data Structure For The Dictionary Problem That Runs In Polylog Time***](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1398562) (Munro, $O\left(\log^2n\right)$)

There are also many algorithms with polylogarithmic factors; $\tilde {O}(\cdot)$ is notation that is used when hiding polylogarithmic factors. So $O\left(n\log^k n \right)\in\tilde {O}(n)$.

Comment: Is this a curated selection of some sort, and if so by which criteria? Or is it the result of a Google Scholar search? That is to say: I think an answer highlighting one problem/algorithm and explaining how the runtime comes about is more useful than a link farm.

Comment: The last paragraph is not related to the question, but thanks for finding the others.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I know, I was just mentioning it.